# Mysql row insert time

Tags: mysql, insert

How to get insert time of rows in mysql without using time-stamp in columns?
Or is it possible of getting each row creation/insertion time in mysql ? If yes , Please let me know.

Comment: I am not used to using mysql to store the time. I always get the time from the server script.

Comment: mysql will not automatically remember creation time for each row, you must do it for yourself.

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich its not duplicate i asked "how to know row insertion(creation) time without using created column in mysql table."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has function `NOW()` or synonymous `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` which contains current datetime.

Ex.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `created`) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', NOW())
```

Without this column there is no chance to get a time when the record was created.

Comment: Thanks Panther,I knew this answer but my question is : how to know row insertion(creation) time without using created column in mysql table.

Comment: @neo: it is impossible using mysql.